# Round get array slice roundly except on array value with same order

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I want to get array slice w/o one element that coming as argument, but slice should be rounded. See example for better understanding.

```
type Positions = "top" | "right" | "bottom" | "left"

const fn = (place : Positions) => {
 const POSITIONS = ["top", "right", "bottom", "left"]
 return getSlice(positions, place) 
}

fn("top") // -> ["right","bottom", "left"]
fn("right") // -> ["bottom", "left", "top"]
fn("bottom") // -> ["left", "top", "right"]
fn("right") // -> ["bottom", "left", "top"]
```

Should works with any array length

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-merkle-9xe9i0?file=/src/index.js something like this

Comment: Just in general, that information should be added to the question.  If for one, do not have access to codesandbox from my work machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can grab the index from where you want to slice the array.

Then create two arrays one to right and one to left using [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and then [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) them.

```js
const fn = (place) => {
  const positions = ["top", "right", "bottom", "left"];
  const index = positions.indexOf(place);
  return positions.slice(index + 1).concat(positions.slice(0, index));
};

console.log(fn("top")); // ["right","bottom", "left"]
console.log(fn("right")); // ["bottom", "left", "top"]
console.log(fn("bottom")); // ["left", "top", "right"]
console.log(fn("left")); // ['top', 'right', 'bottom']
```

Typescript snippet below:

```
type Positions = "top" | "right" | "bottom" | "left";

const fn = (place: Positions): Positions[] => {
  const positions: Positions[] = ["top", "right", "bottom", "left"];
  const index = positions.indexOf(place);
  return positions.slice(index + 1).concat(positions.slice(0, index));
};

console.log(fn("top")); // ["right","bottom", "left"]
console.log(fn("right")); // ["bottom", "left", "top"]
console.log(fn("bottom")); // ["left", "top", "right"]
console.log(fn("left")); // ['top', 'right', 'bottom']
```

**Note**: This answer assumes that the `place` passed to `fn` is one of `"top"`, `"right"`, `"bottom"`, `"left"`.

Comment: I don't know what the expected behavior should be if the value is not found in the list, but I doubt it's what happens by default here.  `fn ("middle") //=> ["top", "right", "bottom", "left", "top", "right", "bottom"]`.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Yeah, that's a valid concern, but since the OP didn't mention anything about how to handle such situations, I've left that for the OP to decide. I've also added a note in my answer highlighting this point.

Answer (score 0):

You can build this atop a more generic `cycle` function, which just cycles an array starting at a given index.  Our main function can then find the index in the array of the given value.  If it's found, we call `cycle`.  If not, we return a copy of the original array.

It looks like this:

```js
const cycle = (xs, n) =>
  [... xs .slice (n), ... xs .slice (0, n)]

const getSlice = (xs, x, i = xs .indexOf (x)) =>
  i > -1 ? cycle (xs, i) .slice (1) : [...xs] 

const positions = ["top", "right", "bottom", "left"]

; [...positions, "middle"] .forEach (
  pos => console .log (`"${pos}" ==> ${JSON.stringify(getSlice (positions, pos))}`)
)
```